# Yahoo finance API: No definition found for Table yahoo.finance.historicaldata

Tags: yahoo-api, yahoo-finance

I have been using the yahooapi for the stock historical information for a year. It had been working perfectly.

However, I am getting this error:
No definition found for Table yahoo.finance.historicaldata

select * from yahoo.finance.historicaldata 
where symbol in ('GOOG') and startDate='' and endDate = '' &diagnostics=false&env=store://datatables.org/alltableswithkeys

Is the yahoo.finance.historicaldata service (REST) still available? If not, any suggestion for the alternative solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://datatables.org/ is down, which is the backend for the community tables that power YQL. 
That's why it isn't working. Not sure about any alternatives though

Comment: It's back up now, and it seems to be much faster than before!